# Disable Help Agent (the lightbulb icon) in OpenOffice.org

Tags: macos, openoffice

How can I turn off the Help Agent (the lightbulb icon) that keeps appearing the in the lower-right corner? I'm running OpenOffice.org 3.2.0 on MaC OS X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can permanently disable the Help Agent on the **Tools - Options - OOo - General dialog**.

[image: Help Agent setting]

Source: http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Help_Agent

Comment: Thanks. The Help Agent is such an annoying feature, they should have defaulted it to off.